# Big Size Video EmguCV

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, video-capture, emgucv

I'm using Emgu CV to create video player. it's working fine with small size video (<500Kb) ,but when i try to play big size video (>20Mb), it shows this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: Unable to create capture from E:\Tugas Akhir\wiman\3a.avi
```

i have emgu cv reference in my project, also have opencv_ffmpeg290_64.dll and other opencv dll in my project.
this is line of code cause this error,

```
string videodir="E:\Tugas Akhir\wiman\3a.avi";
capture = new Capture(@videodir);
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: did you confirm you have that file at that location? I can open more than 1GB avi file, so the size should not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is a bit old but I came across it tracking down a different problem.)

I believe that if you looked in the debugger you are just having an issue with file paths and character escape sequences.

The line:

```
string videodir="E:\Tugas Akhir\wiman\3a.avi";
```

Needs to be one of the following:

```
string videodir=@"E:\Tugas Akhir\wiman\3a.avi";
```

or

```
string videodir="E:\\Tugas Akhir\\wiman\\3a.avi";
```

Without telling the compiler that the slashes are to be taken literally or using the escape sequence for a `\` then what you are passing to Capture is `videodir = "E:Tugas Akhirwiman3a.avi"` which probably doesn't exist (though it is a legal file path in windows) and Capture will throw a null exception if the file does not exist.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem,finally I . With EmguCV in C#, you need to put the opencv_ffmpeg.dll, for example: opencv_ffmpeg2410.dll, be careful if you have x86 or 64 bits